# How to search for changes made to Cassandra to any table from a particular time

Tags: cassandra

I wish to be abe to do a diff of a Cassandra database after a particular operation. This is used mainly for black box testing purposes. Are there any strategies besides looking at each table and seeing what has changed?

Comment: What do you mean: CQL Schema changes or changes in the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in method to track changes in data.

The only approach is to prepare the schema for the queries you are going to make, in this case this involves querying for new data.